# NSTokenField selection

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield, nstokenfield

I've never used NSTokenFields before so I was checking out the Token Field programming guide.  I've read a lot about to interact with an individual token but what if I want to interact with multiple tokens?  I can select multiple tokens at once by holding shift but when I right-click only one of the tokens gets selected.  Is there a way to handle multiple selection?

Also, even though I can shift_select multiple tokens, how can I select multiple tokens at different places (by using command/ctrl?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can only select consecutive tokens by holding the shift key. Everything else doesn't work, because NSTokenField inherits from NSTextField, which doesn't allow multiple selection ranges.